# Diagnosing ASP.NET Azure WebApp issue

Tags: multithreading, azure, azure-web-app-service

since a month one of our web application hosted as WebApp on Azure is having some kind of problem and I cannot find the root cause of that.
This WebApp is hosted on Azure on a 2 x B2 App Service Plan. On the same App Service Plan there is another WebApp that is currently working without any issue.

This WebApp is an ASP.NET WebApi application and exposes a REST set of API.

Effect: without any apparent sense (at least for what I know by now), the ThreadCount metric starts to spin up, sometimes very slowly, sometimes in few minutes. What happens is that no requests seems to be served and the service is dead.

Solution: a simple restart of the application (an this means a restart of the AppPool) causes an immediate obvious drop of the ThreadCount and everything starts as usual.

Other observations: there is no "periodicity" in this event. It happened in the evening, in the morning and in the afternoon. It seems that evening is a preferred timeframe, but I won't say there is any correlation.

What I measured through Azure Monitoring Metric: 
- Request Count seems to oscillate normally. There is no peak that causes that increase in ThreadCount
- CPU and Memory seems to be normal, nothing strange.
- Response time, like the others metrics
- Connections (that should be related to sockets) oscillates normally. So I'd exclude something related to DB connections.

[image: Some metrics]

What may I do in order to understand what's going on?

Comment: Will you will be able to give below information so that I can look at the backend logs ?
1) Web app name
2) Date and Time of the issue in UTC

Comment: Yes, edock-rest.azurewebsites.net. 2) Started yesterday 21 UTC until 8 UTC

Comment: Was happing as well today 11:30 UTC - 13:36 UTC (when I restarted the webapp)

Comment: sorry, *happening

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, this happened to be related to a wrong usage of Dependency Injection (using Ninject) and an application that wasn't designed to use it.

In order to diagnose, I discovered a very helpful feature in Azure. You can reach it by entering into the app that is having the problem, click on "Diagnose and solve problems" then click on "Diagnostic tools" and then select "Collect .NET profiler report". In that panel, after configuring the storage for the diagnostic files, you can select "Add thread report".
In those report you can easily understand what's going wrong.

Hope this helps.